# Переключения текста в Label

Tags: c#, winforms

Подскажите как сделать такого плана переключение текста?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Простой таймер к примеру.

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, например можно создать асинхронный цикл и запихнуть всё в него

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
    Label myLabel;  

    public MyForm()
    {
        myLabel = new Label();
        this.Controls.Add(myLabel);
        this.Load += OnLoad;
    }

    private async void OnLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var closed = false;
        this.FormClosed+= (s, a) => closed = true;

        var messages = new [] {"Hello", "How its going", "Another message"};
        int counter = 0;
        while(!closed)
        {
            myLabel.Text = messages[counter%messages.Length];
            counter++;
            await Task.Delay(1500);
        }
    }
}
```

Вызывается это так

```
var form = new MyForm();
form.ShowDialog();
```

Результат

[image: ...]